# Unable to activate 3D effect in Ubuntu 11.10 Dell Studio Laptop

Tags: 11.10, unity, hardware

I have Dell Studio with a ATI 1 GB dedicated graphics card, I am running Ubuntu 11.10. I have also installed Compiz configuration package.

Once I select necessary options in Compiz I am running the command unity --reset, I will get the 3D effects as long as the terminal is open once I close the terminal, every thing will be messed up and even I will lose the 3D effects.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` . Thank you

Comment: @severin Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

If you passed the

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

test then I would recommend installing CSSM

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

There is a short tutorial here for Cube settings. http://ubuntuguide.net/enable-compiz-desktop-cube-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-unity

Plus you may need to edit some compiz settings therefore install

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

This editor will be able to access the compiz-1 settings

Here is another how to: http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-edit-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu.html